# Using CallAfter to call wxWindow::Destroy generates compile-time error

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to destroy a wxWindow-derived object that is likely to have been subject to a Bind() from one of its container objects.  Based on my reading (and some prior experience chasing weird errors), I believe I need to delay the call to Destroy() until after the event queue has been exhausted, otherwise there is a possibility that the event handler may attempt to access the destroyed object.

What I've been reading says to use CallAfter() to execute the object's Destroy() function.  The problem is, if I call

```
obj->CallAfter(&ObjClass::Destroy);
```

I get a compile error "C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments", pointing to the wxAsyncMethodCallEventFunctor::Execute() function in wx/event.h.  This seems odd to me, given that wxWindow::Destroy() takes no arguments; I thought maybe the instance reference ("obj") was the problem, but when I tried to wedge it into the call other ways, I got errors saying I had too many parameters.

With some experimentation, I've been able to make it work by defining a function in my derived object that takes 0 arguments and (apparently critically) *returns void rather than bool.*  It looks very much like:

```
void ObjClass::DestroyMe()
{
    this->Destroy();
}
```

Now, when I use the expression

```
obj->CallAfter(&ObjClass::DestroyMe);
```

the program compiles and appears to be working.  Still, I hate this solution because it feels klunky.

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Am I correct in thinking the issue relates to the bool vs. void
  return values?

  - If so, can I somehow typecast the function reference to simulate a
    void() function call (since I don't care about the bool value)?

Comment: why not unbind() all those handlers before closing the window or even better in the window destructor?

Comment: I'd have to dig into the event tables to figure out what the bindings were on a case by case basis, which will certainly take more code than what I have already built; my goal is to reduce complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CallAfter()` does expect a `void` callable because it would be dangerous if it took anything and then just discarded the result (because what else could it do with it?), so you can't pass it `Destroy()` directly.

Your workaround is fine but, of course, in C++11 you can make it much shorter and more convenient by using lambdas which go very well with `CallAfter()`, so usually you'd just write

```
obj->CallAfter([=]() { this->Destroy(); });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think what I really need to do is learn lambdas; I've never used them (as far as I know they didn't exist when I learned C++) and until now I've never felt much need to understand them.